# mod-rewrite rule for this url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Can you help create a mod re write rule for this url please

```
http://localhost/view.php?item_id=28&sef=2009-bristol-blenheim-in-west-yorkshire
```

i want it to go to

```
http://localhost/view.php?item_id=28
```

and i want my link to look like this

```
http://localhost/view/28/2009-bristol-blenheim-in-west-yorkshire
```

i am currently using this rule for another page

```
RewriteRule ^category/[!/.]*([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /browse.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]
```

but cant seem to update it to work for this one..

**current htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Browse Category
RewriteRule ^category/[!/.]*([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /browse.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]

# View Item
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /view.php?item_id=$1&sef=$2 [NC]
```

the browse category is working, View item is not

Comment: You need to be clear about what URL you want the visitor to be able to provide, and what path on your server you actually want the request to reach. Giving three paths is confusing, so can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a request such as

```
http://localhost/view/28/2009-bristol-blenheim-in-west-yorkshire
```

to silently become a server request for

```
http://localhost/view.php?item_id=28&sef=2009-bristol-blenheim-in-west-yorkshire
```

Then try this:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /view.php?item_id=$1&sef=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: thanks but i get a 404, will update with my full htaccess file

Comment: fixed it now, you rule works but i needed to add Options -Multiviews to get it to pass the perameters.